# add Text inside the Boxgroup in heat map dc.js

Tags: javascript, d3.js, heatmap, dc.js

is there a way to put a text inside the box group of a heat map in dc.js ? 
so that the information is readable without making a hover on the box ?

```
var ndx2 = crossfilter(budgetsArr);

 var budgetDimension = ndx2.dimension(function(d) {return [+d.account, +d.year]; });
 var  budgetGroup = budgetDimension.group().reduceSum(function(d) { return +d.budget; });



  chart
    .width(45 * 20 + 80)
    .height(45 * 5 + 40)
    .dimension(budgetDimension)
    .group(budgetGroup)

    .keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
    .valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
    .colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
    .title(function(d) {
        return "Account:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
               "Year :  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
               "Budget: " + (d.value) + " $";})
    .colors(["#ffffd9","#edf8b1","#c7e9b4","#7fcdbb","#41b6c4","#1d91c0","#225ea8","#253494","#081d58"])

    .calculateColorDomain();
```

and the result :

[image: Result]

I need that the Budget will be readable from the box and not in the title property.

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of appending the title add the text element try the following code. If it doesn't work put a plnkr link. I can probably help you to figure out the issue. Look at [this link](http://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/7341714) to understand more about adding the text element.

```
 chart
.width(45 * 20 + 80)
.height(45 * 5 + 40)
.dimension(budgetDimension)
.group(budgetGroup)

.keyAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[0]; })
.valueAccessor(function(d) { return +d.key[1]; })
.colorAccessor(function(d) { return +d.value; })
.append("text")
.attr("x", function(d) { return x(d.value) - 3; })
.attr("y", d.value/ 2)
.attr("dy", ".35em")
.text(function(d) { return "Account:   " + d.key[0] + "\n" +
       "Year :  " + d.key[1] + "\n" +
       "Budget: " + (d.value) + " $";}); });
```

Comment: Since this is dc.js and not straight d3.js, you'll need to do a little bit more, but this is basically the right idea. If you just wrap everything from `.append` to the end, inside `.on('pretransition', function(chart) { chart.selectAll('rect.heat-box') ... })` then that's about right. (I think you can also simplify the coordinates since the rects are already in the right place.)